# Booking.com cancellation policy

Tags: bookings

I booked and paid via credit card for a night's stay in Portugal in June. My credit card was charged the full amount in November. Due to covid19, I cannot fly so I checked my hotel confirmation which stated that if I cancel before the 19th of May then a cancellation fee of 30% would be charged which I was okay with. But when I cancelled booking.com stated this was a non refundable booking with no refund which means I would lose 100% of my payment. Surely I am due a refund of 70% of my booking or am I missing something here?

Comment: "if i cancel before 19th may then a cancellation fee of 30% would be charged" when did you cancel? Because if you've done it just now, it's not *before* 19th May (unless you're in a small handful of places near the international dateline - but I imagine that's not the calendar booking.com would work on in any case).

Comment: cancelled 15th may

Comment: Then if you're correct about the cancellation policy, yes you should receive a refund of 70% of the price. Go and check the booking confirmation, and if that's right, contact booking.com. We can't really help you more than that.

Comment: yes im correct about my facts,at the moment booking.com not replying to emails,maybe too busy so i will give them time to reply,then if no joy then its a section 75 claim, thanks for your imput

Comment: Remember that (depending upon where you and the card issuer are located) you may be able to dispute this charge with the credit card issuer as well.

Comment: The problem here is you might have two different set of terms and conditions - the hotels ones say a refund is allowed, but Booking.coms ones might not allow a refund.  If you paid Booking.com, a section 75 chargeback might be rejected because the hotels T&Cs might never have applied in this case.

Comment: the hotel were ok and has given me a credit for the 30% cancellation fee to use against a future booking and they said to contact booking.com for the remainder,so it looks as though its booking.com who are keeping my money